# Where to store user data: in a Sandboxed Mac app container or in Home/Documents?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

Is it safe and recommended way to store user-created valuable data (a single-file database) in an app container? Or should I better store it in Home/Documents/?

Related question: Are Mac Sandboxed app containers backed up by Time Machine by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is in the form of a document, then the user can decide that themselves, as you have read/write access to any folder chosen by the user via a save dialog.

However if it's data that your app uses "behind the scenes" then store it in the `Application Support` folder (see `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSApplicationSupportDirectory)), which happens to be deep within the sandbox container folder.  In this you have no choice anyway, as without explicit permission from the user (which is given by using a save dialog), your app cannot write anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you @trojanfoe. But if I add a temporary exception entitlement `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write` for Documents folder, then can't I store data file there?

Data is in form of a single CoreData 'database', created and editable by user. I used Applications Support folder before sandboxing, what worries me now is if those containers are a safe place. Couldn't they be erased at OS upgrade/reinstall, etc... Can you comment on Time Machine?

Comment: @Indoor Yes, you can do that, but the word "temporary" means support for it can be dropped whenever Apple feel like it.  It sounds to me like this is a bona fide document and you should allow the user to choose where it should be stored.  All the files within a user's home directory are backed-up by Time Machine, and won't be removing during an update, so that shouldn't be a concern.