# Where are the "files" for an iOS app running on M1 Mac?

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1

I finally am able to test my ***iOS*** App on my M1 Mac (had to update to Monterey to get TestFlight).

So, now, since I make a lot of use of files in my app, where do I find them?  Is there an equivalent to "On My iPad" on the Mac?  Is there a "Files" app other than Finder?

I've searched the Google & the stackoverflow, and nothing so far.  Also searched HD drive for a known filename, but nothing.

We have customers asking about our app on Mac, but in some cases they will need to access files.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with M1, just with MacOS.

Comment: I made it clear that I'm talking about an iOS app, which can only run on a Mac with M1 processor.

Comment: M1 is relevant. You can run iOS arm64 apps natively on M1 Macs (instead of compiling for the simulator).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I found it -- just by accident listed a complete path in a log file that I  emailed to myself.

Path is:  /Users//Library/Containers/MyAppName/Data/Documents

The log listing didn't REALLY give the path, though.  The "app name" part was a GUID. Only when I looked at the Container folder did I see my app, and others.

I'm not much of a Mac afficianado, maybe it's obvious that it would be here.

NEW TIDBIT:  I found that deleting the app does not delete the data, as it would in an iOS device.

Comment: There's nothing new here and it has nothing to do with M1. Mac sandboxing has always worked this way. Look for example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948605/where-to-store-user-data-in-a-sandboxed-mac-app-container-or-in-home-documents.

Comment: I meant "new" only to those like me who are much more familiar with iOS than Mac.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. What I'm suggesting is that this whole Q and A is unnecessary, as it duplicates well trodden material. The question was "Where are the "files" for an iOS app running on M1 Mac?" and the answer is, where they always were for any sandboxed Mac app, long before M1 came along.